# Software to customise this USB PC Remote Control

Tags: windows-7, remote-control

I bought [this remote from eBay](http://cgi.ebay.com.au/USB-PC-Remote-Control-Wireless-Controller-Media-Center-/280542208282?pt=AU_Input_Peripherals) and have been trying to customise it ever since. Most of the buttons work but I was hoping I could use something like Autohotkey and WinLIRC to fully personalise every aspect of it. However after trying many remotes from around the house, it appears the receiver won't accept any other signals than from supplied remote. Which explains why WinLIRC (used to get raw IR data) won't work.

Does anyone have any experience with this (or a similar) remote. It's even advertised as being able to shutdown your PC (red button on top left), but for some reason does nothing.

**I just want to customise what the buttons do.** And I'm open for any solution, as hacky as it might be. Hopefully free though.

Oh and I'm on Windows 7.

[image: image of remote]

**Update:** I looked around Device Manager and unplugged/replugged to find the device. It's under 3 *HID Keyboard Device* entries under Keyboard and also as a *HID-compliant mouse*. The Vendor/Product ID (0x073A/0x2230) refers to *Chaplet Systems, Inc* (thanks [whitequark](https://superuser.com/users/25472/whitequark)).

IR reading is out as it seems the receiver translates IR data into keystrokes and mouse movements.

Still, any help with this device would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Why is VID/PID pair not real? It is perfectly OK, the VID maps to `Chaplet Systems, Inc.`.

Comment: @whitequark: OH... the lookup i lookedup must have been totally off. How did you get that, sorry?

Comment: `grep 073a /var/lib/usbutils/usb.ids`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an infrared receiver alone, but an infrared receiver coupled with a chip which translates IR codes received to fake keypresses/mouse moves and sends that using standard HID protocol. Thus, it looks like a Human Interface Device and could only do things the keyboard/mouse can, and AutoHotKey should work fine. You can check what keys are reported to the PC, you can try to use [this application](http://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/home/tef/wintools/keyview.exe), and then write an AHK config.

Comment: yeah, seems like AHK's the best way to go. Though it seems the 'Power' button seems to do absolutely nothing :(

Comment: Power button should work like a power button on a regular keyboard. From reading keymap definitions from Linux sources, I remember that it has its own keycode. Maybe it is intercepted by Windows.