# Remote Control Adapter for PC

Tags: windows, remote-control

Does there exist a product out there that attaches to your PC (preferably USB) that enables Infrared signals to be received (by a regular remote control) ?

It seems a novel idea to be able to get a programmable remote that can be used to manipulate windows (like the Harmony remote control series) along with some programmable software (preferably Windows supported) to convert any button on a regular remote to some command on the PC.

Does this exist?  What is it called?

[This particular instance you are REQUIRED to use the crappy supplied remote, and this is not what I am looking for](https://superuser.com/questions/179457/software-to-customise-this-usb-pc-remote-control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you have a home cinema remote which is programmable? If this is the case I did find this

Visit http://www.sourcingmap.com/laptop-wireless-black-remote-control-usb-receiver-p-128922.html?currency=GBP&utm_source=google&utm_medium=froogle&utm_campaign=ukfroogle

Although it comes with a "Crappy" remote you should be able to program your home cinema remote with this.